Expected Iterations for a binary string to turn into all 1s.
Let $x$ be some binary string of length $n$, and $x_i$ be the $i$th digit of $x$ (from right to left). I'm looking to apply an iterative process to the string. On every iteration, if $x_i$ is equal to 0, then the probability that $x_i$ becomes a 1 would be equal to the number of 1s that appear to the right of the $i$th digit over $i-1$, or $\frac{1}{i-1}\sum_{i<j\le n}x_j$. For example, if my string is 001101, then the second zero has a $\frac{3}{4}$ chance to become a 1 during this iteration, and the 3rd zero is guaranteed to become a 1. The rule/process should be applied to all digits independently during an iteration.
I'm looking to find the expected number of iterations to be applied in order for a binary string in the from 000...001 to turn into 111...111. Using a computational approach with Markov chains, I have results for up to $n = 15$, but I was wondering if there was some algebraic representation for the expected iterations based on $n$. So far the expected number of iterations seems to be bound above by $\log_2n$, but the bound isn't sharp for $n \ge 3$. Any help or potential suggestions for approaches would be appreciated!

Not following the example.  In the string $001101$ the third zero is in the fifth  place, yes?  So wouldn't the probability be $\frac 14$? And for the second zero, in the second place, the "probability" is greater than $1$.  Did you possibly mean to divide by $n-i$?   That would make the probability just equal to the percentage of $1's$ to the right of the given $0$ (and then matches both your values) Or are you somehow numbering from right to left, but defining "after" from left to right?

Also, how does an "iteration" work?  Do all the changes happen at once (to the extent they happen at all) or do the changes happen in sequence, so that a change to one slot can change the subsequent probabilities?

Sorry for the unclear wording - the probability should never be greater than 1, and by after I mean the digits to its right, and indeed the probability should be based on the percentage of 1s to the right of the 0. The iteration should be applied all at once to each digit independently, so changes to one digit should not affect others. I've edited the original question for clarity.

Are you requiring that $x_1=1$?  There's no chance to ever flip a $0$ in that position. Alternately, you could just require that all the digits end up $1$, except possibly $x_1$.  In any case, there's a recursion since the word after the leftmost $0$ doesn't depend on anything to its left.  You'd need to analyze the growth in the number of $1's$ each iteration though...not easy.

Yes, I'm always starting with the string such that the first/rightmost digit is 1 (and all other digits 0).

The problem deserves at least a satisfying presentation. Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $E$ be the set of sequences $x=(x_i)_{i=0}^n$ such that $x_i=0$ or $1$ and with $x_0=1$. Denote $p_{x,i}=\frac{1}{i}\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}x_j$ for $i=1,\ldots,n.$ Denote also $Z_x=\{i; x_i=0\}.$ Consider the Markov chain $(X_t)_{t=0}^{\infty}$ on $E$ defined by $X_0=(1,0,\ldots,0)$ and its transition probability
$$\Pr(X_{t+1}=y|X_t=x)=\prod_{i\in Z_{X_t}}p_{X_t,i}^{y_i}(1-p_{X_t,i})^{1-y_i}$$  if $y_i=x_i=1$ for $i\notin Z_x.$ And $\Pr(X_{t+1}=y|X_t=x)=0$ if this condition is not fulfilled.  Denote $T=\inf\{t; Z_t=\emptyset\}.$ Find $E(T).$
I am not offering any progress in this interesting question, just a bit of clarification (if I understood well). This was too long for a comment.
My suggestion  would be to find some proper martingale adapted to the problem.

Thank you for the formalization/clarification, it indeed does nicely explain the problem that I was describing.
